# Sheaf homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}(D)$ and dually to $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, line-bundles

I am reading Daniel Huybrechts Complex Geometry. I don't understand how these two maps are defined.

[image]

The description of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is given in the answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1749343/414708

My knowledge of sheaf theory and algebraic geometry is limited. Could you please tell me how these maps are defined.

Comment: He takes the tensor product of $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}(D)$ with $\mathcal{O}(-D)$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987624/why-is-the-ideal-sheaf-mathcali-y-equal-to-mathcalo-y-and-not-math?rq=1). There are many posts about exact sequences of hypersurfaces. Two small remarks:

1. the map $s: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(D)$ is uniquely determinant by the image s$(1)$. This defines a global section of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(D)$. $Y$ is defined as the zero locus $Z(s)=(s)_0 \subset X$ of this section.
2. Dually, the map $\mathcal{O}(-D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}$ can be seen as an embedding as the ideal (sheaf) $I$ in $\mathcal{O}_X$ that cuts out $Y$. then $Y$ has sheaf of sections $\mathcal{O}_D\cong\mathcal{O}/I$.

**Edit**: Explaining every detail is 2 chapters in Hartshorne but: The line bundle $\mathcal{O}(D)$ has global sections $s_i$ sucht that their zero locus $(s_i)_0$ define hypersurfaces $Y_i\subset X$ which is "linear equivalent" to $Y$. If you're new to all of this, don't go too hard on this and think of $Y_i \sim Y$ like homotopic equivalence in algebraic topology. The two hypersurfaces are somehow equivalent in an algebraic geometric sense (they differ by multiplying with a rational function).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am struggling to understand this. First could you please tell me that is there a relation between the irreducible hypersurface $Y$ and the divisor $D$, or $D$ could be any divisor.

Comment: I edited and gave an overview on how to approach this, but it's a lot of theory, nothing one understands by just reading a post! this is basically one year algebraic geometry class...